# OnClick and New Tab Opened, Redirect (Page Visibility API)

Tags: javascript, redirect, visibility

I am trying to create a redirect (to a thank you page) when someone clicks a link within an ad (in an IFrame) on our site. I am thinking I could do this with a simple onclick event combined with detecting if a new tab is opened since I cannot listen for an onclick on the links within an iframe. I have found the Page Visibility API, which seems like the correct thing to use (since .blur is activated when they click on an iframe, even if they click on white space in the iframe instead of a URL) but all the scripts that I've found are a bit too complex for me to decode and simplify into something I can use. This is an example of what I'd like to do, and what I thought should work, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
document.onclick = function() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        console.log("New window opened");
        window.location.replace("www.example.com/thanks");
    } else {
        console.log("Click");
        // Do nothing
        return;
    }
}
```

When I click on the page I do get the "click" response, but when I click on a link and open a new window I don't get redirected, nor do I get the redirect.

EDIT: I see now that my problem is that I am not detecting ANY clicks at all within an iframe, even with a whole document listener. Is there a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I was actually able to figure out this issue on my own with a little more time of trial and error. Here is an example of how I did it:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            window.location.replace("https://example.com/thanks");
        } else {
            window.self.focus();
        }
    }, 200);
});
```

Using window.blur instead of window.onclick made it so I was sure someone clicked within the iframe. If they clicked within the iframe I then checked to see if the window was visible anymore. If it is then they didn't open a new tab, and I set the window back into focus incase they click within the iframe again. If they did open a new tab (the window is hidden) then I send them to our thank you page! I also set a breif timeout to allow the browser time to recognize that the window is hidden (without this It was not working!).